# Firebase Analytics for games (measure time on each level)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm building a game and I want to have access to information such as "which level is the most difficult?", or "how much time does a user spend on average in easy difficulty and how much on normal difficulty?", and so on.

Seems that Firebase Analytics will solve this problem but I'm not sure if I have to use predefined or custom events and parameters.

Currently when a user completes a level, I log the following event:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("difficulty", levelDifficulty); //easy, normal, advanced, etc.
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.LEVEL, levelName); //the name or index of the level, for example "Level 1"
bundle.putLong(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.VALUE, duration); //seconds passed to complete the level
analytics.logEvent("level_ended", bundle);
```

a) Will I be able to get the information I need with that simple event?

b) Do I have to use a predefined event or a custom event? Similarly, do I have to use predefined or custom parameters on that event?

c) If I use any custom events or custom parameters, will Firebase collect these events automatically or do I have to register these custom events or these custom parameters in the Firebase console?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a custom event.  Follow [these instructions](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7397304?hl=en&ref_topic=6317489) to get that set up.

You will only be able to see the properties of custom events when you [export them to BigQuery](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en) for analysis.  You won't be able to see them in the console.

Comment: Thanks, Doug. In BigQuery, will I be able to see the average time per difficulty and stuff like that?

Comment: Sure, you can construct a query to show that.  It's extremely powerful.

Comment: Sorry, Doug, one last question: What's the purpose of registering the custom parameters for each event in the Firebase console? Is it for logging or for analyzing the data? For example, if I am logging a custom event with custom parameters in my app, will I be able to analyze that event in the Firebase console (or in BigQuery) without registering the custom parameters? Or should I register all custom parameters before publishing the app?

Comment: I'm not terribly knowledgable about Analytics, but there's a limit to how many events and parameters you can have, so I imagine registering them in the console prevents you from making a mistaking in your app and using them up by accident.